# Creating single squared tile fishnet buffer based off shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, vector-grid, grids-graticules

I'm interested in creating a fishnet buffer around a current grid I have. The fishnet buffer I'm interested in making needs to be exactly the same cell size and extend just one grid cell around the AOI.

How can I create such a result using ArcGIS Desktop?

The grids are square. I've provided an example of what I would like to the result to look like.

[image]

Comment: Is your "current grid" raster or vector?

Comment: @Polygeo I'll update the questions to include that as well. I haven't tried Arcpy though, that would be great. Vector grid

Comment: How did you create the original vector grid?  Assuming it was using the Create Fishnet tool what parameter values did you use?

Comment: There's a reason ArcGIS supports both vector and raster datatypes, and it has mostly to do with how unwieldy vectors become when they are fine enough to overlap pixels one for one. Once you create such a monster (expect a fortyfold increase in size, vice an *uncompressed* raster), you'll likely want to revisit your interest in creating same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of many possible solutions with arcpy flavour:

```
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management("fish_net-1","../POINTS.shp", "ALL")
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("POINTS", "POINT_X_Y_Z_M")
```

Select upper right point and move it NORTH half of original fishnet width and EAST by the same amount. You can use:

```
arcpy.Point( !POINT_X!+1000/2, !POINT_Y!+1000/2)
```

on field Shape in field calculator to achieve this. /Note width of my original fishnet was 1000./
Move lower left point SW using similar expression.

Compute new fishnet using points extent:

[image]